# How to reduce Drawcalls for animated GameObjects?

Tags: animation, optimization, graphics, rendering, unity-game-engine

I have a scenario such that I have a wall and whenever player hits the walls it falls into pieces .Each of the piece is the Child GO of that wall.Each of the piece is using same material .So I tried Dynamic Batching on that but it didn't reduce the draw calls.

Then I tried CombineChildren.cs it worked and combined all meshes thus reducing the drawcalls but whenever my player hit the wall it didn't played the animation.

I cannot try SkinnedMeshCombiner.cs from this wiki  with the answer from this link [check this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/327730/what-should-i-do-1.html)

beacause my game objects have **Mesh renders** rather than **Skinned Mesh renderer**

Is there any other solution I can do for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So I tried Dynamic Batching on that but it didn't reduce the draw
>   calls.

Dynamic batching is almost the only way to go if you want to reduce draw calls for moving object (unless you try to implement something similar on your own).
However it has some limitations as explained in the [doc](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/DrawCallBatching.html).

Particularly:

- limits on vertex numbers for objects to be batched
- all must share the same material (not different instances of the same material - be sure to check this)
- no lightmapped objects
- no multipass shaders

Be sure all limitations listed in the doc are met, then dynamic batching should work.

> Then I tried CombineChildren.cs it worked and combined all meshes thus
>   reducing the drawcalls but whenever my player hit the wall it didn't
>   played the animation.

That's because after been combined, all GameObjects are combined into an unique one. You can't move them indipendently no more.

Comment: how about changing the mesh renderer of the GO(wall) to SkinnedMeshRenderer & applying SkinnedMeshCombiner.cs to it?

Comment: skinned mesh renderer are automatically attached to meshes when they are imported and are skinned (contains a rig). You won't gain anything in doint that.

Comment: okay I did something like combining the non animated portion of the wall into one mesh by modifying the CombineChildren and all the other animated child GOs of the wall into each separate mesh all of them were now batched together with dynamic batching.The only thing I am worried about now is ,it is drawing vertices like 150K.Is this amount fine or I need to reduce it?

Comment: 150K vertices for a single wall seems quite a lot. Could you edit your question and clarify exactly how your models are composed? (hierarchy, vertices number per model, etc..)

Comment: not for a wall but for the whole scene that is composed of many of these walls.Basically this is the vertex count of all my paths that is being rendered by the camera.The maximum drawcalls I am having are 32 and minimum drawcalls are 14. Are these stats ok for the whole scene or something is wrong?

Comment: 32 shouldn't be too much. I'm currently working on a mobile game that reaches even 40/50 dc and the fps are stable enough.

Comment: hi @Heisenbug I want to have chat with with an issue of smooth turning of the character ?Can you help me with that .. I know it is off topic but I have searched alot but didn't find any help

Comment: @hariszaman: please post a question and I'll have a look at it when I have a time.